# How to select the one equals to each others in Sparql

Tags: sparql

For example,there is one simple select sparql query:

```
SELECT *  Where  
{
  CT:A skos:broader ?A.  
  CT:B skos:broader ?B.  
  FILTER(?A=?B)  
}
```

With the `FILTER`,it is easy to select the objects that equal to each others.
But when there are even more triples to match ,for example,from `CT:A skos:broader ?A` to `CT:Z skos:broader ?Z`,how can I filter those meet `?A=?B=?C=....?Z?`
Wish to make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your query should be written as

`select ?a where { ct:a skos:broader ?a. ct:b skos:broader ?a }`

which means that you want to find an `?a` whose the value of `skos:broader` for both `ct:a` and `ct:b`. If you want to make the equivalent for all `ct:a, ct:b, ... ct:z` then you just repeat the pattern:

`select ?a where { ct:a skos:broader ?a. ct:b skos:broader ?a. ct:c skos:broader ?a ... ct:z skos:broader ?a }`